# Using Sheets.Copy results in an automation error when trying to Copy a worksheet in a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro which should load a selected workbook, extract a specific sheet from there and then add this sheet to my original workbook.

The error is an automation error.

Here is my code so far:

```
Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
Dim strFile As String
Dim thisWB As Workbook
Dim importWB As Workbook

Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fd
   .Filters.Clear
   .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx?", 1
   .Title = "Choose an Import file"
   .AllowMultiSelect = False
   .InitialFileName = "C:\"

   If .Show = True Then

       strFile = .SelectedItems(1)

   End If
End With


Set importWB = Workbooks.Open(strFile)
Dim exportSheet As Worksheet
Set exportSheet = importWB.Sheets("export")

importWB.Close False

thisWB.Activate
exportSheet.Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
```

My guess is that the way I am trying to add the sheet from the importfile is wrong.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't you close the importwb before you try to read what type the exportsheet is? I also think you need to use the type-property of of exportsheet, a worksheet is probably the wrong object for the type-argument?

Comment: Yes, but I store the sheet in the variable exportSheet so I shouldn't need the other workbook to be open anymore?
I looked the Add method and adjusted the question. I need to use the Copy Method, Add just adds a template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Set exportSheet = importWB.Sheets("export")` does not create a copy of the export sheet. It creates a variable with a pointer to the sheet. So if you close the workbook with the export sheet your pointer references nothing.

The `Type` parameter of the `Worksheets.Add` method declares what type of worksheet excel is supposed to add.

If you want to create an empty worksheet of the same type as the export sheet you would do it like this:

```
'...
Set exportSheet = importWB.Sheets("export")
thisWB.Worksheets.Add Before:=thisWB.Sheets("Sheet1"), Type:=exportSheet.Type
importWB.Close False
```

If you want to copy the sheet you would do it like this:

```
'...
importWB.Sheets("export").Copy Before:=thisWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
importWB.Close False
```

Comment: Good catch, bugs me that I didn't realize the pointer. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to leave your `importWB` open during exportation. Close it after it's done.

You should be able to export the sheet with this code:

```
exportSheet.Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
importWB.Close False
```

This will copy the `exportSheet` before first sheet, but you may adapt it to your needs.

Hope this helps